# What is the best and easiest way to turn off SQL Server when not in use?

Tags: sql-server

Situation: developer workstations that typically just use the client tools to connect to other non-local sql servers. However, there are rare times that having the full version of sql server to do local development will be beneficial. In an effort to not waste system resources running sql server all the time I would like to know the best way to "turn it off" while still allowing usage of client tools (management studio, etc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may need to access SQL Server Configuration from the Start menu by selecting Microsoft SQL Server and then Configuration Tools, and then follow Thomas' path.

You can also **configure those services so that they don't start automatically**. I have mine set on "Manual", so if I want to use the SQL Server server, I just start the service. Ditto for SSIS, SSAS, SSRS, etc.

Since I have two versions of SQL Server running on my development machine, I don't want all of this stuff eating up my resources.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a fan of PowerShell for this. Depending on the details of what you want to accomplish:

Stop a particular instance:

```
Stop-Service 'MSSQL$InstanceName' -Force
```

and

```
Start-Service 'MSSQL$InstanceName'
```

or to stop all SQL related services.

```
Stop-Service *SQL* -Force
```

or create a double-clickable script to toggle the state:
http://orionseven.com/blog/2010/10/18/starting-and-stopping-sql-server-with-windows-powershell-2-0/

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> Right Click -> Stop.

Answer (score -1):

this video shows the easiest and advanced ways to start/re-start and shutdown SQL Server

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-lgFv9uL4Y

Comment: Videos can be taken offline. Please detail the different ways you can start/re-start and shutdown SQL Server